# Java - "Live" output from Systemcommand

Tags: java, cmd, live

I've made a little GUI for youtube-dl, but for this project, I nedd kind of a "live" output from a system command. I already tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/), but this only displays the output when the process has finished. I need something which displays the progress of my download continously (youtube-dl is just a command line tool, so it needs to refresh about every second).

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting a new Thread by hitting the Download-Button by using:

```
Runner = new Thread(this, "ExternalProcessTest");
Runner.start();
```

in the Listener.

Additional Infos about GUI-Threads could be found here: [non-blocking Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942233/java-help-with-non-blocking-thread-that-runs-an-external-process)

Some additional approaches for progress bars in a console: [progress-bar console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843202/how-to-show-percentage-progress-of-a-downloading-file-in-java-consolewithout-ui)

Comment: Thank you! Willt ry thaat. But my solution works for me, too! :D

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching, I found the answer:

My Problem was, that the Terminal, where "System.out.println()" prints its output to, didn't refresh. It just wrote the outout after the Process finished, but because I'm writing a Download client, you have to see the progress of your Download. So I've done it this way:

[Get output of terminal command using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915319/get-output-of-terminal-command-using-java)